# How to fetch one item from a JSON feed with the item ID using Typescript / Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I have a service.ts file with the following code that gets data from a JSON feed:

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  private _heroesUrl = '/heroes.json';  

  getHeroes() {
    return this.http.get(this._heroesUrl)
      .map(res => <Hero[]>res.json().data)
      .do(data => console.log(data)) 
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }

  getHero() {
    //** code to go here
  }
}
```

And a component file that uses the service:

```
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
   heroes: Hero[];
   selectedHero: Hero;
   errorMessage: any;

   constructor(private _router: Router, private _heroService: HeroService) { }

   getHeroes() {
       this._heroService.getHeroes()
       .subscribe(
       heroes => this.heroes = heroes,
       error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
   }

   getHero() {
     let id = this._routeParams.get('id');

     //** code to go here
   }

}
```

Now, getHeroes() works just fine and fetches all items from heroes.json via service.ts. However, what I'm trying to do is fetch just one item from heroes.json using the "id" of the item. How do I go about doing this? I tried using .filter but that didn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should use filter method of data, not Observable:

```
 getHero(id) {
     return this.http.get(this._heroesUrl)
        .map(res => (<Hero[]>res.json().data).filter(hero => hero.id === id))
        .do(data => console.log(data)) 
        .catch(this.handleError);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I am too late , but this worked fine for me.

Here is the code snippet from my service.ts

```
 getProject(id: number) {
       console.log(id);
       return this.getProjects()
              .then(projects => projects.filter(project => project.id == id)[0])
              .catch(this.handleError);
      }
```

And this is how it is consumed from my component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      if (params['id'] !== undefined) {
        let id = +params['id'];
        this.projectsvc.getProject(id)
          .then(proj => this.currproject = proj);
      }

    });
  }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do it could be as follow.

In service.ts :

```
getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
    return this.getHeroes()
        .map((heroes: Hero[]) => heroes.find(hero => hero.id === id));
}
```

And in component.ts :

```
getHero() {
    let id = this._routeParams.get('id');
    this._heroService.getHero(id)
            .subscribe(
                hero => this.hero = hero,
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```